# One-time FMU execution with fmi_adapter

Tags: ros2, fmi

I'm launching a Simulink FMU in ROS 2 with the [fmi_adapter](https://github.com/boschresearch/fmi_adapter).

```
ros2 launch fmi_adapter fmi_adapter_node.launch.py fmu_path:=FMI/Trajectory/RobotMARA_SimulinkFMU_v3.fmu
```

It's working fine, but the FMU is being evaluated constantly, i.e., it never finishes. This is strange to me since I've define a `tend` in the Simulink Model.

Does anyone know if there is the option to limit the FMU execution to only once?

Answer (score 0):

End times are currently not considered by the ROS fmi_adapter. I created an issue at https://github.com/boschresearch/fmi_adapter/issues/10 with few more details and to discuss a possible implementation.